# Outlook Web Add In with Graph API - Is it possible to include current item as an attachment when forwarding/sending an email?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I want to be able to send my current item as an attachment to another mailbox as an 'Outlook Item'. This would include any attachments attached to my current item.

I have used the graph API to return my current item in its entirety, but its the forwarding this as an attachment part im struggling with.

Im using this doc as a guide and at Request 3 it touches on attachments , but i havent seen anyone attach an Outlook item as an attachment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I would rather forward the current item as an attachment as opposed to just forwarding the message body, but im not sure if this is possible ?

Any insight on this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the ItemAttachment resource type to add the message/event/post as attachment. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itemattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0) for it!!

Comment: Thank you!! Ive got it working after reading that doc, much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear that it above had helped :)

Comment: Let me move this to answer. Consider upvoting/accept it as answer. So it can be useful to others in the community as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ItemAttachment resource type to add the message/event/post as attachment. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itemattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0) for it!